How to trigger a confirmation modal before leaving a page in Nuxt 3 and Vue 3
I need help implementing a page leave confirmation in my e-commerce website's product buy page. If a user enters the page and tries to leave without interacting with the confirmation, the confirmation should still be triggered. The confirmation should have two buttons: "Stay" and "Leave". The user should be able to leave the page or stay on it based on their choice.
i try several way and cant understand the perfect method that's why i'm here
the issue i'm facing when i try to leave this page it trigger when i click on the page any nav link but if i click on browser navigation back button then it trigger and Url update if user refresh it change page and also if user repeat by click navigation button then also facing issue
what i expected
when user try to leave page show the confirmation without changing url and anything and after click leave navigate away and if click stay close the Modal i'm using ant-design Modal and userStore is pinia auth user stored
and also i facing some bugs that i solved by rasing flag but not completly solve the problem so i try different way and finaly here
this more close but not correct solution
const modalVisible = ref(false);
let navigationResolve = null;

const leaveConfirmation = (title, content) => {
  if (modalVisible.value) {
    return navigationResolve;
  }
  modalVisible.value = true;
  navigationResolve = new Promise((resolve) => {
    Modal.confirm({
      title: title,
      content: content,
      okText: 'Leave',
      cancelText: 'Stay',
      // icon: h(ExclamationCircleOutlined),
      okButtonProps: {
        style: {
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: 'white',
        },
      },
      cancelButtonProps: {
        style: {
          backgroundColor: '#50C878',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: 'white',
        },
      },
      onOk() {
        resolve(true);
      },
      onCancel() {
        resolve(false);
        modalVisible.value = false;
        navigationResolve = null;

      },
    });
  });

  return navigationResolve;
};

onBeforeRouteLeave((to, from, next) => {
  if (userStore?.user?.data) {
    if (isEditing.value) {
      leaveConfirmation('Do you want to leave?', 'Are you sure you want to leave? Your changes may not be saved.')
        .then((leave) => {
          if (leave) {
            next();
            window.history.pushState({ modal: false }, '', `${to.path}`);
            Modal.destroyAll();
          } else {
            next(false);
          }
        });
    } else if (!isEditing.value && !handleOrder.value) {
      leaveConfirmation('Do you want to leave?', 'Are you sure you want to leave? Your order will be cancelled.')
        .then((leave) => {
          if (leave) {
            next();
            window.history.pushState({ modal: false }, '', `${to.path}`);
            Modal.destroyAll();
          } else {
            next(false);
          }
        });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});


In Nuxt3, you can leverage the Vue Router and the beforeunload event to display an alert when the user is about to leave or close the page. Here's how you can set it up in your page.vue:
    function beforeUnload(e: Event) {
        const confirmationMessage = 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?'
        e.preventDefault()
        e.returnValue = true // Gecko + IE, for old browsers
    }

    // Vue Router's navigation guard
    const route = useRoute()
    const router = useRouter()
    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
        if (from.fullPath === route.fullPath) {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this page?')) {
                next()
            } else {
                next(false)
            }
        } else {
            next()
        }
    })

    onMounted(() => {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnload)
    })

    onBeforeUnmount(() => {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnload)
    })

The beforeUnload function handles the beforeunload event to show a default browser confirmation dialog when the user tries to close the browser tab or window.
Custom dialogs like SweetAlert cannot be used for the beforeunload event due to browser security restrictions.
